# Does Lenovo Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Dock work with Thinkpad L480?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, thinkpad, docking-station, thunderbolt, usb-c

I just picked up the Lenovo Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Dock and connected it to my Lenovo Thinkpad L480. The problem is, that my laptop doesn't recognize the dock. I have installed the Thinkpad Thunderbolt 3 Driver

https://support.lenovo.com/de/en/solutions/acc100356

uninstalled it again after it didn't work and installed it again - still no connection. Then I tried to install the firmware which also didn't help as I needed to be connected to the dock (which doesn't seem to work) I tried another USB-c port, but that also didn't work out

Is there a problem with connecting a thunderbolt cable to a USB-c port? Shouldn't I at least see the dock?

[image]

Comment: Wouldn't this be far better addressed to Lenovo themselves?

Comment: Model of thunderbolt dock?

Comment: Model No. DBB9003L1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically, thunderbolt and USB are two totally different interfaces that can use the same (USB C) connector.

USB C is a port standard that can support a whole bunch of modes for both power and data, but as far as I can tell none of them are mandatory.

A USB C port on a PC will almost certainly support USB host mode, but what else it supports is highly variable. Thunderbolt is a relatively expensive feature, so unless it is explicitly stated that a port supports thunderbolt it most likely does not.  Reading the specs for your laptop I see no mention of thunderbolt, so your laptop is probablly not compatible with thunderbolt peripherals.

Comment: What wonders me is that the driver is called "thinkpad_thunderbolt-3_dock_and_usb-c_dock_driver_v10017.exe".
So the word USB-C is in the name and I, therefore, thought it also would work on my laptop, which has USB-C.

Comment: lenovo seems to offer both a USB C dock and a thunderbolt dock, presumablly the driver package covers both.